# Find the function that equals to $1-x^3+x^6-x^9+ \cdots$

Tags: calculus, power-series

> Find the function that equals  to $1-x^3+x^6-x^9+ \cdots$ for all $|x| < 1$

I know that $\frac{1}{1+x} = 1-x+x^2-x^3+...$ But I couldn't find the pattern here

Answer (score 2):

Hint: if $|f(x)| < 1$ then $$\frac{1}{1+f(x)} = 1 - f(x) + f(x)^2 - f(x)^3 + \dotsb$$

Answer (score 1):

Substitute $y=x^{3}$
$$S = 1-y+y^{2}-y^{3}+\cdots$$
$$S = \frac{1}{1+y} = \frac{1}{1+x^{3}}$$

Comment: oh, that's genius!